# window.external throwing error (Unexpected call to method or property access.) in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using WebBrowser control in WinForm Application. 
When it hits the external method then it gives following error"Error: Unexpected call to method or property access."

Below is the code:

```html
<html>
</head>
<body>
<p id ="demo"></p>
<button onclick="window.external.XYZ(12345)">
 Say hi to the form
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Same code works fine on the machine which has Internet Explorer 8.

Please help me out.